# Could not find artifact org.opcfoundation.ua:opc-ua-stack:jar:1.4.1.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, opc-ua

I am getting the error

"Could not find artifact org.opcfoundation.ua:opc-ua-stack:jar:1.4.1.1-SNAPSHOT,"

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.opcfoundation.ua</groupId>
<artifactId>opc-ua-stack</artifactId>
<version>1.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but the same project works on my other computer(windows) with the same Java version, the same Maven version, and the same pom.xml but my current(Mac) pc can't compile the project.

In the pom.xml file, the following dependency is causing the error is:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
nice -n 10 /Users/orcunkiris/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-20.0.2.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jna/aarch64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dpreload.project.path=/Users/orcunkiris/Desktop/Projects/OSKONBOARD/oskonboard-be "-Dpreload.config.path=/Users/orcunkiris/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/options" -Dexternal.project.config=/Users/orcunkiris/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/projects/oskonboard-be.3c9fe0af/external_build_system -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=7287641511109038889 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=tr -Duser.country=TR -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2023.2 "-Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents" "-Didea.config.path=/Users/orcunkiris/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2" "-Didea.plugins.path=/Users/orcunkiris/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/plugins" -Djps.log.dir=/Users/orcunkiris/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.7 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/orcunkiris/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/compile-server/oskonboard-be_f9879ec5/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true "-Djps.kotlin.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/var/folders/xb/j5p48t9x7q14f4_k_q1l6qm80000gn/T/kotlin-idea-4666991428620443662-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util-8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/platform-loader.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/protobuf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jps-model.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/forms_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util-8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-runtimeModuleRepository-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/JPA/lib/jps/javaee-jpa-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 50664 5ba9d440-3966-4fab-b346-420129583da5 /Users/orcunkiris/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/compile-server
nice: /Users/orcunkiris/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-20.0.2.1/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

When I run 'maven clean install' or 'maven clean install -U,' I receive this error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.368 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-21T11:05:36+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sm: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.osk.dashboard:sm:jar:1.4.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opcfoundation.ua:opc-ua-stack:jar:1.4.1.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I have tried changing the JDK version, my current Maven version is: 3.8.1(added manually), and my current SDK is coretto 1.8 that rewriting it, but it still doesn't work. Can you please help?

Comment: The dependency does not exist... why using a SNAPSHOT version? Use releases...instead...

Comment: My dependency like this:
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.opcfoundation.ua</groupId>
   <artifactId>opc-ua-stack</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
How can I change my version from SNAPSHOT

Comment: So the problem it gives you an error about the SNAPSHOT dependency, but you use a regular one?

If you are using IDEA, check Dependency Analyzer to see if the dependency is declared as SHAPHOT somewhere else.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#dependency_analyzer